# Materiliaze view in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

How to create/refresh materialize view in oracle 10g.

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle documentation here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2063793)

Comment: Can you please provide me syntax and basic rules.

Answer (score 0):

**CREATE:**

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_mview 
AS
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**REFRESH:**

`REFRESH` is simply used like `exec dbms_mview.refresh('example_mview');`

or within the structure like

REFRESH + refresh how

```
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW example_mview     
  REFRESH COMPLETE
  AS
  SELECT * FROM table_name
```

ex.

```
REFRESH FAST
REFRESH COMPLETE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
```

See the documentation for other options.